# Ruby ssh error Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed while it works with PHP

Tags: ruby, authentication, ssh

I try to connect a server though SSH using Ruby, but I have an Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed error. The problem is that it works in PHP.

Here's my ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
include Net
domain = 'ks2.so.d-sites.com' # insert IP address or domain name here
begin
Net::SSH.start( domain, 'webistrano', :verbose => :debug, :keys => ['/home/webistrano/.ssh/id_rsa', '/home/webistrano/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'], :port => 22 ) do |ssh|
print "connected"
end
rescue Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch => e
  puts "remembering new key: #{e.fingerprint}"
  e.remember_host!
  retry
end
```

And I get this errors:

```
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.974862 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3f8c5d3a06a0]: establishing connection to ks2.so.d-sites.com:22
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.975912 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3f8c5d3a06a0]: connection established
I, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.976039 #24165]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3f8c5d39edc8]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.981160 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3f8c5d39edc8]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1-hpn13v10'
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.981231 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3f8c5d39edc8]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.3.0 x86_64-linux'
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.982272 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: read 856 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.982418 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 852
I, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.982517 #24165]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3f8c5d39e418]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.982690 #24165]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3f8c5d39e418]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.982883 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 716
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.982960 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: sent 720 bytes
I, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.983003 #24165]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3f8c5d39e418]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.983161 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3f8c5d39e418]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.983207 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3f8c5d39e418]: exchanging keys
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.983416 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:02.983469 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.024146 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: read 152 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.024270 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.027331 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.027409 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: sent 144 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.032446 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: read 720 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.032563 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.035433 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.035505 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.035617 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.035954 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3f8c5e189fdc]: beginning authentication of `webistrano'
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.036081 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.036130 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.074777 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: read 52 bytes
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.074912 #24165] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f8c5d39f250]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.075018 #24165] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3f8c5e189fdc]: trying password
E, [2012-03-06T20:40:03.075077 #24165] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3f8c5e189fdc]: all authorization methods failed (tried password)
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.3.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:200:in `start': webistrano (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
    from ssh-test.rb:6
```

I wrote a simple PHP code, and it works:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('ks2.so.d-sites.com', 22);

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'webistrano',
                          '/home/webistrano/.ssh/id_rsa.pub',
                          '/home/webistrano/.ssh/id_rsa')) {
  echo "Identification réussie en utilisant une clé publique\n";
} else {
  die('Echec de l\'identification en utilisant une clé publique');
}
```

Is there someone that can help me?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found how to solve that problem: adding a `:auth_methods => ['publickey','password']` parameter in the `Net::SSH.start` function.

Comment: checkout also `:non_interactive => true`

Comment: Simply doing `ssh-add` and trying again worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that error before,try uninstalling the gem 'net-ssh',try this:gem uninstall net-ssh -v 2.8.0, it works for me,
refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21566548/3159604

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the Net::SSH.start solution but opted to  `set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true, :auth_methods => 'publickey'}` which seems to work on my end.

Noted that Initially, I just used  set :ssh_options, `{:forward_agent => true}` on 3 machines running on FreeBSD, CentOS and MacOSX and it worked fine - even used on production releases, however after testing on a VBoxed Vagrant-based CentOS (6.4) machine it stopped working. So, adding auth_method did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just running `ssh-add` (in the terminal) and trying again (to deploy) worked for me.

Comment: Adding the necessary key to your SSH Key Agent with `ssh-add` is a workaround for the failures of `Net::SSH`. In my particular situation, using a Key Agent is complicated, necessitating looking for a fix for this Ruby failure.