# Capistrano SSH::AuthenticationFailed, not prompting for password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I've been using capistrano successfully for a while now and all of a sudden in every project I've lost the ability to deploy.

Environment:

- os X (Mavericks)
- ruby 1.9.3p194
- rvm (locally, not on server)
- rails 3.2 and up
- RubyGems 1.8.25

I'm not using rsa_keys or anything I want capistrano to prompt for user and password. Suddenly it has decided not to ask for a password, but does ask for user. Then it rolls back and gives me the following error.

```
[deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: sub.example.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@sub.example.com)
connection failed for: sub.example.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@sub.example.com)
```

This has occurred on my personal laptop and my iMac at work. It occurs when deploying to two different servers (both linux)

I'm completely at a loss here. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to login ssh manually?

Comment: yes, that works in every case

Comment: See also this net-ssh issue, where the problem is currently being discussed: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/145

Comment: Is this issue for Capistrano 2 or 3? For Capistrano 3 I believe the README for "Using password authentication" says:  
set :password, ask('Server password', nil)
server 'server.domain.com', user: 'ssh_user_name', port: 22, password: fetch(:password), roles: %w{web app db}

It's very uncomfortable to fill the password this way instead of prompting like it was before :(

Comment: Setting :password does not resolve this issue in Capistrano 2 with anything after net-ssh 2.7, I would suspect this is an issue for Capistrano 3 as well.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Figured it out! Apparently this issue was with `net-ssh` gem. I had version 2.8.0 installed recently with some updates to my development environment and was the cause.

I'm not sure why it was failing, but `gem uninstall net-ssh -v 2.8.0<` fixed it for me.

If anyone actually knows why this was an issue or how I can correct this issue with the newer version of `net-ssh` I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: Anyone else who runs into this should be aware that locking net-ssh at 2.7.0 and net-ssh-gateway at 1.2.0 worked for me.

Comment: After remove, i have a error: Could not find 'net-ssh' (>= 2.0.14) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: After you uninstall net-ssh 2.8.0, make sure you have another version installed to satisfy other gems dependencies, like 2.7.0

Comment: So for instance run `gem install net-ssh -v 2.7`

Comment: I added `gem 'net-ssh', '~>2.7.0'` next to `gem 'capistrano', '~>2.15.5'` in my Gemfile and ran `bundle update` afterwards.

Comment: Where is the `Gemfile` located on a Mac?

Comment: Your Gemfile is located in the root of your Rails App. If you're using Capistrano outside of a rails app then you'll just need to handle this w/o bundler gem uninstall ...

Comment: This is still a problem through net-ssh 2.9.1  butnet-ssh 2.9.2 (when it is released) does prompt for password again. It doesn't however, use capistrano's :password parameter. That still only works in 2.7

Answer (score 18):

**The answer may break your rails app due to gem dependancies.**

The issue is with net-ssh as was correctly answered by [Sparkmasterflex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1313409/sparkmasterflex), however whilst this will get capistrano working ok it may break your rails app:

These steps fixed both capistrano and rails for me ...

1. In your Gemfile add `gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'`
2. Run `bundle update net-ssh`
3. Run `bundle` (just to be sure everything is working ok'
4. Run `gem uninstall net-ssh -v 2.8.0`

If you are a rails user you should now be able to run both the rails server and capistrano.

Comment: I followed the steps and it printed "Using net-ssh 2.7.0", but I still got error: ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'net-ssh' (>= 2.8.0) - did find: [net-ssh-2.7.0] (Gem::LoadError)

Answer (score 12):

I have a workaround that doesn't require downgrading `net-ssh`, per a comment at the [link](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/145) that [Zach Lipton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405154/zach-lipton) posted. Place this code in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :ssh_options, {
  config: false
  #Other options...
}
```

After I did that, I got another error, `Error reading response length from authentication socket.` Found the solution to that [here](http://www.antleon.com/2014/04/rails-capistrano-deployment-ssh-error-reading-response-length-from-authentication-socket/). Execute these commands at your Bash prompt:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
$ ssh-add
```

Comment: Just running `ssh-add` and trying again worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Upgrading your net-ssh version to 2.8.1 will solve the problem. They released a version bump in 19th february 2014 that fix this and other problems.

1. Uninstall your current net-ssh gem (gem install net-ssh -v 'version')
2. Just paste this on your Gemfile:

   gem 'net-ssh', '~> 2.8.1', :git => "https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh"
3. Run bundle install

Comment: Yet, it was net-ssh-2.9.1 that broke this for me. So, if they fixed it in 2.8.1, they broke it again. Reverting to an older version fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem while deploying using capistrano 
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deployer@IP

ssh-copy-id deployer@ip

This will add your keys to server and you can login without password.

Comment: on mac osx, you may need to first `brew install ssh-copy-id`

Comment: This way is so much easier. Always use this technic. :)

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. Believe it or not, active password protection is a requirement in some organizations.

Answer (score 3):

```
set :ssh_options, {
 verbose: :debug
}
```

... helps a lot!

I had an issue that I generated my public and private keys with `puttygen` and exported private key as OpenSSH with name `<somename>.id_rsa`. An then saved public key with name `<somename>.id_rsa.pub`.

( ! ) The public key puttygen saves is in RFC 4716 format not PEM. Use `public` suffix instead of `pub` for public key file-

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for me:

```
group :development do
  #.....
  gem 'capistrano', "~> 2.15"
  gem "net-ssh", "~> 2.7.0"
  #.....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to connect to your server with certificate (file.pem) with this command:

```
ssh -i "file.pem" user@yourServerIp
```

Then try to run cap production deploy. It solved error for me. I think it is because time limit for certificate expired.

Answer (score 0):

If all the above solutions doesn't work,please restart your system as you might be facing the issue due to net-ssh host connections.when you restart and enter the deployment command ,it will ask to add the identity to known hosts.