# Capistrano deploy does not ask for password then fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I ran a commit, and then deployed and my deploy crapped out. There is no problem ssh'ing into the server with the command line, and I did multiple multiple deploys just an hour earlier with no problems.  This is a Rails 4 app:

My commit that I did:

```
  [master 0c92b35] twilio
 11 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/add.png
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/movie.png
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/playlist.png
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/recipe.png
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/2086c2b65ce01314d6232b55cc84bc9f
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/4d8b49ba8a5b8572d8f08833b225a279
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/9d4f937775816a3dbe9de2dee94230a1
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/c69324afb35cfd4bd4494d80f5647107
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/e9bceb7d6e65c52be41b8d3d4afe2044
 create mode 100644 tmp/cache/assets/development/sprockets/f634b1ecacd2fa5a47b6c29762ec28ac
 create mode 100644 tmp/pids/server.pid
```

My error in the console when deploying:

```
FATFROG:fix andrew$ cap deploy
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2014-02-08 20:32:53 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-02-08 20:32:53 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2014-02-08 20:32:53 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:blackpond/gift.git master"
    command finished in 1180ms
  * executing "git clone -q -b master git@github.com:blackpond/gift.git /home/deploy/giftlift/releases/20140209033254 && cd /home/deploy/giftlift/releases/20140209033254 && git checkout -q -b deploy 0c92b3555320c7881c70a37714558c09472b3d31 && (echo 0c92b3555320c7881c70a37714558c09472b3d31 > /home/deploy/giftlift/releases/20140209033254/REVISION)"
    servers: ["107.170.47.246"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deploy/giftlift/releases/20140209033254; true"
    servers: ["107.170.47.246"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: 107.170.47.246 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@107.170.47.246)
connection failed for: 107.170.47.246 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@107.170.47.246)
```

My Deploy.rb file:

```
load 'deploy/assets'
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :default_environment, {
 'PATH' => "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/:$PATH"
}

set :rvm_type, :user
set :application, "***"
set :repository,  "***"

set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control 

set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, false
ssh_options[:port] = ***
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{application}"
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :branch, "master"

role :web, "***"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "***"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server

namespace :deploy do  
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem [Capistrano SSH::AuthenticationFailed, not prompting for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560297/capistrano-sshauthenticationfailed-not-prompting-for-password%5D.%20I%20imagine%20that%20the%20fix%20is%20the%20same:%20reinstall%20net-ssh). I imagine that the fix is the same: reinstall net-ssh.