# Rails 4 + Capistrano + AWS Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I followed [**this**](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/) tutorial to deploy my ***Rails 4*** app using ***capistrano*** to ***AWS*** and having a hard time solving this issue.

When I run `cap production deploy`, it fails with the below error

```
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy
```

Below is the is ***full trace***

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
** Invoke rvm:check (first_time)
** Execute rvm:check
DEBUG [2439e1e0] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version on 52.37.242.197
DEBUG [2439e1e0] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:25:in `create_or_reuse_connection'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:173:in `ssh'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:126:in `block in _execute'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:76:in `capture'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:check
```

According to this [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560297/capistrano-sshauthenticationfailed-not-prompting-for-password) post I tried locking `net-ssh` at `2.7.0` and `net-ssh-gateway` at `1.2.0` but the error still persists. Any help is appreciated.

***Environment:***

*OS - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*

*Ruby - 2.2.3p173*

*Rails - 4.2.5*

*Capistrano - 3.4.0*

*net-ssh - 2.7.0*

*net-ssh-gateway - 1.2.0*

Comment: How's your machine and server authenticated?

Comment: @Nithin I'm connecting to the server with this command `ssh -i "/home/pavan/Downloads/myfile.pem" ubuntu@52.37.242.197`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with net-ssh as was correctly answered by Sparkmasterflex, however whilst this will get capistrano working ok it may break your rails app:
These steps fixed both capistrano and rails for me:

1. In your Gemfile add gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'
2. Run bundle update net-ssh
3. Run bundle (just to be sure everything is working ok'
4. Run gem uninstall net-ssh -v 2.8.0

If you are a rails user you should now be able to run both the rails server and capistrano.