# Authentication issue in Cap production deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ssh, amazon-ec2

Issue

> (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks) cap aborted!
>   Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user
>   user@xxyy
>
> Tasks: TOP => rvm:check (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I am following [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/deploy-your-rails-app-to-aws/) tutorial to deploy rails app into my ec2 instance and am at the step where I key in `cap production deploy`

I have tried the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560297/capistrano-sshauthenticationfailed-not-prompting-for-password) post, but am unable to resolve the situation.

Also, I have checked to ensure that my .pem file is located in the .ssh folder in my home directory. I am able to manually ssh into my ec2 instance.

How do I overcome the error above?

Notes:

1) Content of my `production.rb`

`server 'xx.yyy.zz', user: 'abc', roles: %w{web app db}`

2) `net-ssh` version is `3.1.1`. I did not specify this gem in my Gemfile, but still found it from Gemfile.lock.

Comment: could you paste your `production.rb` file content?
what is  your `net-ssh` gem version?

Comment: sure, have included in the post.

Comment: Did you create the `deploy` user? Did you copy the public RSA key to the `authorized_keys` file of the deploy user on AWS? Can you re-check that you followed all the steps of the *"Setup the server"* tutorial chapter? You should be able to log in without needing the `-i` option and your PEM file, to the `deploy` account on AWS, just using the keys.

Comment: 1. where is your `ssh_options` in production.rb file?
2. `net-ssh` gem should be added on the gemfile. version 2.7

Comment: Is it pulling from your Git depository host like Bitbucket? The server's public key is allowed to read from this repository?

Comment: Yes, I did create `deploy` . Am using bitbucket - is the approach different than from github? Checking up on the rest

Comment: And are you able to log in manually as the `deploy` user without any options / passwords?

Comment: I'm able to login manually like this - ssh -i ".../abcd.pem" ubuntu@ec2instancenurl